# sql total of invoices for reserved products

Tags: sql

This is the reserved table:

```
res_nr   product_nr  price   amount  customer_id
1000        20        15       1       4000
1001        21        10       5       5055
```

and this is the invoice table:

```
seq_nr    invoice_nr      product_nr    price     amount    res_nr
500         222             12          5           1        null
501         223             20          10          3        1001
502         223             89          25          1        null
```

I need to write a query with join to have all reserved. In total_invoice I should have the total of invoice which containts the reserved product.

```
res_nr   total_reserve (price*amount)   total_invoice (price*amount)
1000             15                              null       
1001             50                              55
```

- For res_nr 1001 the customer reserved 5 products of nr 21. But he bought only 3 of them + 1 of not reserved product nr 89. (invoice nr 223)

Comment: how to calculate total_invoice value 55 for res_nr 1001? also res_nr 1001 is reserved product nr 21 but in invoice table it use product nr 20.

Comment: Like I wrote, the customer reserved 5. But he bought only 3 of product_nr 21 (3*10) and he bought 1 of not reserved product nr 89 with price 25. (30+25=55)

Comment: You should include the sql version that you use (tsql, oracle, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find an indicative solution [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=086f57c5fb1da09bb74974f28e9a8b96)

You could get your output by performing 2 `LEFT JOIN`. The `temp` table is created in the subquery and calculates the total for every invoice. This information is linked to your original invoice table with the invoice number as a key. Only then you could join to the reserved table with the resource number being the key.

```
SELECT R.res_nr, R.price*R.amount AS reserved_total, temp.invoice_total
FROM Reserved AS R
LEFT JOIN invoice AS inv
ON R.res_nr=inv.res_nr
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT invoice_nr, SUM(price*amount) AS invoice_total
  FROM invoice
  GROUP BY invoice_n
  )temp
ON inv.invoice_nr = temp.invoice_nr
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `r.res_nr` is unique in the `reserved` table, I think it would be like this:

```sql
SELECT r.res_nr, (r.price*r.amount) AS [total_reserve], i.total_invoice
FROM reserved AS r
INNER JOIN (

   SELECT j.res_nr, SUM(j.price*j.amount) AS [total_invoice]
   FROM invoice AS j
   GROUP BY j.res_nr

) AS i ON r.res_nr = i.res_nr
```